# Couchdb v1.1.0 `Object.keys is not a function`

Tags: couchdb

On my local osx setup, I have couchdb v1.0.2 installed.  I wrote several script against this version all of which worked fine.

On my remote debian 6 server, I originally had couch v0.11.0 installed.  Unfortunately, several of my scripts caused an `Object.keys is not a function` exceptions to be thrown.  I figured v0.11.0 had an old version of javascript, so I upgraded to couch v1.1.0.  I followed these [instructions](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_Ubuntu).  After a bit of grief, I finally got v1.1.0 running, but the errors did not go a way.  I'm still seeing `Object.keys is not a function` exceptions.  I've confirmed that v1.1.0 of couch is installed by running `couchdb -V` and I've kill/restarted all instances of couch, beam, and erlang several times.

Any idea what's going on?  I upgraded couch, but do I also have to upgrade the js engine separately?  Are remnants of the v0.11.0 hidden somewhere?  I used `apt-get remove couchdb` to uninstall v0.11.0.  I had used apt-get to install it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you have v0.11.0 remnants.

But you are correct: the "Javascript" in CouchDB is not built-in but rather linked into the system `libjs` or `libmozjs`.

I am unsure how to get a newer Spidermonkey version on OSX however many people (including me) use my [Build CouchDB](https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb) tool for exactly this purpose. It bundles its own Spidermonkey build which *does* have `Object.keys`, `Array.isArray`, and my favorite, `[].reduce()`. The CouchDB build will not be *integrated* into your OS deeply (ultimately, it just runs `make install`). But for the most part, on OSX and Linux it is as simple as running `rake`.

If you do try Build CouchDB, please report an issue in GitHub if you encounter any problems! I try to keep it as well-running as possible on current OSes.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Everything seemed to work when I used Build CouchDB.  Unfortunately, I'm now seeing "reserved slot index out of range" every time I query against couchdb.  Minimal repo: `echo var a = 1 > test.js; ./couchjs test.js`.

Comment: I figured out the problem.  It turned out I had several versions of `libmozjs` installed (used `dpkg -l | grep moz` to find out).  Once I removed used them using `dpkg -r <package>` the couchdb generated from build-couch started working correctly.

Comment: Awesome! Good luck with your project.